# How to package vm for KVM/QEMU?

Tags: qemu, kvm

Is there any existed method to package the installation of a virtual machine for KVM/QEMU?

I mean a single file which QEMU can import into it, just like ova/ovf for vmware.

Currently, I write a script with "virt-install" and iso file to install an OS.

It is OK, but is there better method? Only a single file packaging "virt-install" and iso file, or something like that.